# How to send Email Programmatically in Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

I want to send email programmatically. For that, i wrote the below code:

```
if(field == m_btnSend)
    {
        Store store = Session.getDefaultInstance().getStore();
        Folder[] folder = store.list(Folder.SENT);
        Folder sent = folder[0];

        Message msg = new Message(sent);
        Address receipent[] = new Address[1];
        try
        {
            receipent[0] = new Address("arindam.hit@gmail.com", "Arindam");

            msg.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, receipent);

            msg.setSubject("Test Mail");

            msg.setContent("This mail is to remind you that programmatically we can send the mail");

            msg.setPriority(Priority.HIGH);

            Transport.send(msg);

        }

        catch (Exception e) 
        {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I am runnig it in MDS simulator. Now i want to see this mail in by mail inbox if i open my mail through simulator browser. How it is possible??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code to send the attachments with mail and it works very well on device:

```
 private  void sendmail()
 {
 try
 {
 Address[] address = new Address[1];
 address[0] = new Address(" "," ");
 Folder folders[] = Session.getDefaultInstance().getStore().list(Folder.SENT);
 msg=new Message(folders[0]);
 msg.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
 msg.setSubject(" ");
 SupportedAttachmentPart attach = new         SupportedAttachmentPart(multipart,"application/pdf",pdfName,data);
 multipart.addBodyPart(attach);
 msg.setContent(multipart);
 Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_MESSAGES,new MessageArguments(msg));

 try
 {
Transport.send(msg);
}
 catch(SendFailedException  e)
 {
  System.out.println("messages for sent : : : :   : : "+e.getMessage());
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code in my site. [sending-email-with-attachment-in Blackberry](http://www.codinguru.com/2011/08/sending-email-with-attachment-in.html)

Comment: Hey, I have code..i already showed that. And it is working fine. But how can i get that in my mail??

Comment: what do  you mean by But how can i get that in my mail??  you want to test in device?

Comment: I do not want to test in device. I am using BlackBerry Email and MDS Services simulator 4.1.2. In the ESS simulator, it is asking for password and user name. I am not getting, what are the credential i have to give there.

Answer (score 0):

First read [this](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/6338/Start_the_BB_MDS_Simulator_607563_11.jsp) After running your code in blackberry jde simulator from start->All programs->Reasearch in motion->select MDS then Read this [documentation](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/6338/Send_a_message_607578_11.jsp).Do steps till 6 and you will see your mail sent via your programmed application in the Messages folder
you don't have to enter  password and user name

Answer (score 0):

Try this code - 
For sending email, BIS is active in your device. It will not work in Simulator. Also an email is configured in your device.

```
                         try 
                            { 
                            recipients[0]= new Address(id_,name_); 

                            //add the recipient list to the message 
                            msg.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, recipients); 

                            //set a subject for the message 
                            msg.setSubject("Test email"); 

                            //sets the body of the message 
                            msg.setContent("123456789---------------"); 

                            //sets priority 
                            msg.setPriority(Message.Priority.HIGH); 

                            //send the message 
                            Transport.send(msg); 
                        } 

                        catch (Exception me) 
                        { 
                            Dialog.alert(me+"");
                            System.err.print(me); 
                        }
```